# Cookie is not working while redirecting in .NET 7

Tags: c#, cookies, setcookie, .net-7.0

I need set cookie to redirect request but it's not working.. Everywhere everybody setting the cookie to `Response` property to `Cookies` but when I do it same so it's not working..

My Code:

```
        var token = "myToken123";
        var url = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Client:BaseUrl", string.Empty);

        Response.Cookies.Append("Token", token, new CookieOptions
        {
            Domain = url,
            IsEssential = true,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(123),
            Secure = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        });

        Response.Redirect(url!);
```

Comment: What is different from the way you are doing it than when it is working?  Are you using c# while others are using different apps?

Comment: No, I was looking for C# .NET tutorials and all doing it this way.. but for me it's not working and I don't know why.. :(

Comment: Are you saying everybody is using the exact same method and code?  Than issue must be your machine or network.  You may be using WiFi and others may be using ethernet.  Or you are using a different network.  You may be going through a proxy while others may not be using a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- The `Domain` parameter of your cookie most probably poinst to another domain domain. You can't set cookies on other domains. This is forbidden for security reasons and won't work
- The `Secure` parameter in your code forces the cookie to be only accepted over HTTPs, your site possibly works locally, over HTTP

Comment: Ok, so problem was the domain.. because BE runs on different domain than FE